# Using QString replace method to change filename with regular expressions

Tags: c++, regex, qt

I want to convert a string that looks like this: "/d/r/e/filename.csv" to "/d/r/e/filename D9.csv". I use regular expressions just because im practicing, i know i can do it differently.

Im trying:

```
QString string("/d/r/e/filename.csv");
string.replace("([\\w]+)(?=\\.csv)", "\\1 D9");
```

But doesn't seem to be working, i just get the same string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting the same string because you're not using QRegExp there:

```
string.replace(QRegExp("([\\w]+)(?=\\.csv)"), "\\1 D9");
```